# make python accept json via the web

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web

I have a web server and can run python on it, like this:

```
import os
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl

def main():
    thestring = os.environ["QUERY_STRING"]
    parameter_dict = dict(parse_qsl(thestring))
    print(parameter_dict)

print("Content-Type: text/plain")
print("")
main()
```

If I hit is like this: http://127.0.0.1/web.py?hello=world
I'll get a nice little hash:

```
{'hello': 'world'}
```

That works just fine for my purposes.  Now what I'm trying to do is make this webserver accept json input.

I'm using this code to 'throw' json at the URL

```
body = {
    "username":"user1",
    "folder":"folder1"
}

req = urllib.request.Request("http://127.0.0.1/web.py")
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
jsondata = json.dumps(body)
jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')   # needs to be bytes
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
content = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
print(content)
```

But what do I need to do in my top section of code to have web.py 'accept' the json and be able to use it?  Ideally just put the json into a dict.  I bet this is just something really simple and I'm just missing a basic command.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `requests` module is capable of both sending and receiving json data. Moreover it has a built in `requests.get(url).json()` method that you may be looking for.